# Error while updating macOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra

I'm trying to install High Sierra 10.13.3 Supplemental Update. But I'm getting an error, which is 'The request timed out. (-1001)'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reboot your entire network, all hardware, then puter. Try again. If the same, try tomorrow.

Comment: Why should he try tomorrow? How does that help?

Comment: Reset your internet connection. That is the culprit here. Unplug the modem and then reconnect it.

Comment: I've been trying for three days but I can not update.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson  - because, having worked support for nearly 10 years, it's the kind of 'advice' that pulls out extra info from the OP, usually of the previously unmentioned 'what I tried already' variety ;-)

Answer (score -3):

You need a VPN or to change your network. It seems there is a firewall blocking the Apple server.

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons why a Mac is not able to reach the App Store server. Based on what do you assume that a VPN will solve the problem?